# Cannot save data to MongoDB Compass

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I'm learning Nodejs with Express and Mongo. I watched a tutorial on Youtube and tried to make a simple online store. Everything is fine: I can save name, address, phone, and email of customers who filled in the form to Mongo, but the problem is that I cannot save the correct products' data if there are 2 or more different products. Mongo only receives data of the last product, which you can see in the image below. Here are parts of my code:

```js
// My Order's schema
var orderSchema = Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
    },
    product: [{
        image: String,
        title: String, 
        price: Number,
        qty: Number,
    }],
    /* subtotal: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    total: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    } */
});

var Order = module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

```js
// My Product's schema
var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

```html
<!-- Form for the customers to fill their information -->
<form action="/orders/confirm" method="POST">
    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address" required>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number: 0123456789" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Product</label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                <table class="table table-stripped align-mid">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Subtotal</th>
                    </tr>
        
                    <% var total = 0; %>
                    <% cart.forEach((product) => { %>
                        <% var sub = product.qty * product.price; %>
                        <% total += +sub; %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img class="cpi" src="<%= product.image %>" alt="<%= product.slug %>"></td>
                            <td><%= product.title %></td>
                            <td><%= product.price %> VND</td>
                            <td><%= product.qty %></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><%= sub %> VND</td>
                        </tr>
                    <% }); %>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" align="right"><b>Total: </b><%= total %> VND</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm Order</button>
        
    </form>
```

```js
// Routing
router.post('/confirm', (req,res) => {

    var name = req.body.name;
    var address = req.body.address;
    var phone = req.body.phone;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var cartData = req.session.cart;

    req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('address', 'Address is required!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('phone', 'Phone number is required!').notEmpty();
  
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        res.render('order_info', {
            errors: errors,
            cart: cartData
        });
    } else {
        Order.findOne((err,order) => {
            if (err) {
                res.render('order_info', {
                    errors: errors,
                    cart: cartData
                });
            } else {
                var total = 0;
                cartData.forEach((product) => {
                    var sub = product.qty * product.price;
                    total += +sub;

                    order = new Order({
                        name: name,
                        address: address,
                        phone: phone,
                        email: email,
                        product: [{
                            image: product.image,
                            title: product.title,
                            price: product.price,
                            qty: product.qty,
                            subtotal: sub,
                        }],
                        total: total
                    });
                });

                order.save((err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(order);
                        req.flash('success','Order Confirmed.');
                        cartData.length = 0;
                        res.redirect('/products/all')
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    }
});
```

[image]

(I add 2 products to cart, the first product's price is 5000000, and the second one is 3500000)

I've tried many ways but nothing works. Please help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Your schema should be
var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem's solved, but a new one comes up. I cannot save the correct data if there are 2 products or more. Would you please show me what's wrong in my code.

Comment: It seems here `cartData.forEach((product) => {` you are creating a new order for each item in the cart. You should refactor it to calculate the sub total, and total, then save the order with the final data, So you will be creating a new Order outside the loop